# Why fluentd-cloudwatch Kube deamonSet cannot send logs from specified dir to cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd, amazon-eks

I applied a fluentd-cloudwatch DeamonSet in EKS using config file as this: [fluentd.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/changkaizhao/alpha/master/fluentd.yml)

**Situation ONE**: with `line 302` - `line 313` commented in `fluentd.yml`, everything works well. I can see the new created **log group** and **log streams** in **CLOUDWATCH PANEL**.

**Situation TWO**: with `line 302` - `line 313` uncommented in `fluentd.yml`, **fluentd** cannot send any log data into **CLOUDWATCH**. **log group** and **log streams** are not created automatically.

I check the file `/logs/fun-practice-log/server.log.0` exists in **fluentd-cloudwatch pod**.
The content in `server.log.0` as below:

```
unknown - 2019-11-21 00:42:44,588 - WARNING - 404 GET /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document (10.10.130.37) 0.38ms
unknown - 2019-11-21 00:42:44,818 - WARNING - 405 CONNECT 34.116.211.122:80 (10.10.130.217) 0.51ms
unknown - 2019-11-21 00:42:45,752 - WARNING - 405 CONNECT 34.116.211.122:80 (10.10.130.217) 0.64ms
f6c5a62f536a4444bbb12c0e45973141 - 2019-11-21 02:17:19,605 - INFO - 200 POST /fun_practice/v1.1/get_stat?user_token=seYBtp39Uko0lfsYoDBrQlZV8SWuF (10.0.15.188) 895.95ms
```

I want to stream the logs in folder `/logs/fun-practice-log/` to **CLOUDWATCH** using `source` as below, I cannot figure out what I miss in config file.

```
    <source>
      @type tail
      @id in_tail_svc
      @label @hostlogs
      path /logs/fun-practice-log/server.log.0
      pos_file /logs/fun-practice-log/server.log.pos
      tag host.svc
      read_from_head true
      refresh_interval 5
      <parse>
        @type regexp
        expression /(?<request_id>[^ ]*) - (?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) - (?<log_type>[^ ]*) - (?<message>.*)/
        time_key timestamp
        time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%z
      </parse>
    </source>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out what I did wrong in `fluentd.yml`.
I should not set `mountPath: /logs/account-svc-log` and `mountPath: /logs/fun-practice-log` to `readOnly: true`.
Just remove the args, everything works fine.

Comment: ret `readOnly: true` make **fluentd** cannot record in that path. it leads to some problems.